# how to prove an n*n matrix defined by Aij=1/(i+j-1) is a positive define matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

how to prove an n*n matrix defined by Aij=1/(i+j-1) is a positive define matrix?

i've tried to calculate the principal minors of A, but it seems not working

Comment: This is known as the [Hilbert matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix). If you search for its name, I suspect that you’ll find a proof fairly quickly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Ben Ok, thank you.

Comment: In particular, [my proof here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4309076/81360) shows that the matrix is positive definite (in order to show that the matrix is invertible).

Comment: @Ben Thank you so much for your help. You have solved my problem.

Comment: @Dietrich Yes, it does. Thanks.

Comment: @Oliver Yes, it does. Thanks.